# Too many open files - Failed to initialize inotify: the user limit on the total number of inotify instances has been reached

Tags: compass-sass, inotify

How can I fix below problem? I am using compass.

```
   Too many open files - Failed to initialize inotify: the user limit on the total number of inotify instances has been reached.
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/rb-inotify-0.9.5/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:64:in `initialize'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:66:in `initialize_worker'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/adapter.rb:87:in `initialize'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:31:in `initialize'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/adapter.rb:226:in `works?'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/adapter.rb:190:in `usable_and_works?'
org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:1425:in `all?'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/adapter.rb:190:in `usable_and_works?'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/adapter.rb:57:in `select_and_initialize'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/adapter.rb:55:in `select_and_initialize'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/listener.rb:291:in `initialize_adapter'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/listener.rb:283:in `setup'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/jruby/listen-1.3.1-patched/lib/listen/listener.rb:65:in `start!'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:405:in `listen_to'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:338:in `watch'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb:46:in `watch!'
    /home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:41:in `perform'
file:/home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/compass-app.jar!/app_watcher.rb:12:in `watch!'
file:/home/rmack/Downloads/compass.app/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:447:in `watch'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually a linux config issue.  [Increase the number of files open](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/) in the `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

It looks like you're using Mac OS in which case you should use sysctl.  [Add the following](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/maximum-files-in-mac-os-x/) to the `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kern.maxfiles=your new value kern.maxfilesperproc=your new value
```

Comment: This helped me, but is there any downside of increasing this?

Answer (score 75):

**For Linux**:

Check current value of `max_user_instances`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```

increase that value:

```
$ echo 256 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```

In order to make that change permanent you can always add a line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 256
```

If your system has a `/etc/sysctl.d` directory, you would rather put your custom settings in a separate file like `/etc/sysctl.d/60-local.conf`.

Comment: I get `Permission denied`, even when running `sudo echo 256 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances` (on Debian). The solution of @gcs_dev worked for me (`sudo sh -c ...`)

Comment: That's weird, the command only switches from your current shell (e.g. `bash`) to `sh`. On Debian you could try `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256`

Comment: hey, @0__ , your sudo isn't working because you're running 'echo 256' as root and then trying to do the redirect as your current user, which cannot write to the target.

Comment: I also got `permission denied` error but I have done the command using `sudo su` and it worked.

Comment: To write to the file as root, you need the `sudo` on the second half of the command, the part that is actually doing the write. Instead of `>`, you can use `tee`, and invoke it using `sudo`, like this:  `echo 256 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances`

Comment: worked liked a charm. Thanks. I was facing this issue when doing a sbt build in intellij.

Answer (score 4):

Solved for me: https://github.com/guard/rb-inotify/issues/23#issuecomment-22997846

```
# increase inotify file watch limit
ofile=/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
sudo sh -c "echo 8192 > $ofile"
cat $ofile
rerun app.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu 22.04, it doesn't work:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 256 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances'
```

instead must be used this in order to change it temporarily:

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192
```

It does work what it has been commented previously:

Get current value:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```

In order to save it permanently, add this line:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 256
```

with this command:

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is described in other comments, you can try to find application which does not work correctly with the file system.

But in some cases it is alright, only some application (in my case Felix OSGI cache) has too many open files and limits are too low.

Then open `/etc/security/limits.conf` and add line with limits for the user or group, ie.:

```
dmatej          soft    nofile          10000
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I Increased max_user_watches, max_queued_events, and max_user_instances

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events

echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```